# How to retrieve the selected value of a RadioGroup

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.ios, monotouch.dialog

Considering the code below (Xamarin - c#), how would you retrive the selected value of the RadioGroup?

```
var root = new RootElement ("Meals") {
    new Section ("Dinner"){
        new RootElement ("Dessert", new RadioGroup ("dessert", 2)) {
            new Section () {
                new RadioElement ("Ice Cream", "dessert"),
                new RadioElement ("Milkshake", "dessert"),
                new RadioElement ("Chocolate Cake", "dessert")
            }
        }
     }
}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I stopped coding for a while and when I came back I realized how to do it:

```
    private void Save()
    {
        List<Element> elementList = new List<Element> ();
        elementList = Root [1].Elements;
        foreach (Element element in elementList) {
            RootElement radioElement = (RootElement)element;
            user.Title = radioElement[0].Elements[radioElement.RadioSelected].Caption;
        }
        user.Save ();
    }
```

Comment: You could've also saved them in a class-variable (instead of new'ing it up in the object initializer) and just accessed them directly when trying to save.

Comment: Yes, that makes sense. Thank you!